Constraint Transformation in SCIP
I am using pyscipopt 4.3.0 (python 3.11.5; SCIP 9.0.0) to solve the following binary linear problem:
import pyscipopt as scip

_Name = "tiny_test"
m = scip.Model(_Name)

y1 = m.addVar(name="y1",vtype="I",lb=0.0,ub=1.0)
y2 = m.addVar(name="y2",vtype="I",lb=0.0,ub=1.0)
z = m.addVar(name="z",vtype="I",lb=0.0,ub=1.0)

m.setObjective(z,"maximize")

m.addCons(y1==1.0,name="C1")
m.addCons(y2==1.0,name="C2")
m.addCons(z<=y1+y2,name="C3")

m.optimize()

The unique optimal solution is (y1,y2,z)=(1.0,1.0,1.0) and the optimal objective value is 1.0.
I get the following output:

Why does SCIP detect infeasibility?
When I look at the the model in lp format, it does not reflect what I intended to formulate:
\ SCIP STATISTICS
\   Problem name     : tiny_test
\   Variables        : 3 (3 binary, 0 integer, 0 implicit integer, 0 continuous)
\   Constraints      : 3
Maximize
 Obj: +1 z
Subject to
 C1: +1 y1 = +1
 C2: +1 y2 = +1
 C3: +1 z -1 y1 -1 y2 = +0
Bounds
 0 <= y1 <= 1
 0 <= y2 <= 1
 0 <= z <= 1
Binaries
 y1 y2 z
End

Is this related to the internal constraint transformation, or am I missing something here?

I looked into examples for how to use pyscipopt but could not see any issues with my modelling code.
I searched for similar issues online but could not find any related discussions.


could you please try using this constraint:
m.addCons(z-y1-y2<=0,name="C3")

It is basically related to some constraint transformation. In the output it is correctly stating that all variables are binaries. And it correctly gets first two contraints, but then you see this  C3: +1 z -1 y1 -1 y2 = +0 what means 1 * z - 1 * y1 -1 *y2=0. And basically this creates infeasibility.

Obviously, the file problem is infeasible. Again, the question is why does SCIP detect feasibility.

also I've checked your code and it works with my python and scip verions. which ones are you using? I'm using Python3.10 and pyscipopt==5.0.0

Thanks @JohnnyCheesecutter! After an attempt to update pyscipopt and a restart of my Spyder environment, I also got the correct solution.

For completeness: The issue reoccured. After uninstalling and reinstalling all python components and SCIP it finally seems to work correctly. Weird corruption in the background…
